# Direct discourse and capitalization

Tags: capitalization

I am studying the English Problem Solver book from Practice Makes Perfect Series* and stumbled on a strange instruction at page 12:

[image: Page 12 of Practice Makes Perfect: English Problem Solver]

It says that a quote does not begin with a capital letter unless it is the first word in a sentence. The fourth example contradicts this rule, doesn't it?

- Practice Makes Perfect English Problem Solver: With 110 Exercises 
  by Ed Swick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got this one.

The *direct discourse (direct quote)* capitalization rule is to capitalize first letter of a quote, whereas in the *indirect discourse (indirect quote)*, the capitalization is no required unless the word itself requires capitalization.